# How to change path Id in svg file?

Tags: javascript, svg

I get svg code from sever and I have to change some specific path's Id.

(e.g. In the code below I want to add something to the preProcessor for changing the Id of the path that has been manipulated, to "targetPath" so I can access the path in useEffect hook.)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SVG from 'react-inlinesvg';

const PaintObject = ({ objectdata, selectedColor }) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#fff');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      const path = document.getElementById('targetPath');
      path
        && path.addEventListener(
          'click',
          () => setColor(selectedColor),
          false,
        );
    }
  }, [loaded, selectedColor]);

  return (
    <SVG
      src={objectdata.image}
      style={{ color }}
      onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}
      preProcessor={(code) => code.replace('fill="#fff"', 'fill="currentcolor"')}
    />
  );
};
export default PaintObject;
```

Comment: @RobertLongson not helping.The file has several paths and I don't  have the path Id so I cant use getElementById and then use setAttribute

Comment: also please say the problem before voting negative so I can edit the question if needed

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok. thanks for the tip. I have added a Simplified version of the code

Comment: How you gonna find the paths you want to change their ids?

Comment: @Hossein I want the path that has "currentcolor" in it

Answer (score 2):

`.replace(/id=".*?" fill="currentcolor"/, 'id="targetPath" fill="currentcolor"')`

adding this to preProcessor was the solution .